# toggle array of image when button is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this html, I want to know if it is possible to toggle this images when the button is clicked, but only displaying one at a time, using jquery

```
<div class="section">
            <img class="changeimg" src="images/cresta.svg">
            <img class="changeimg" id="none" src="images/longitud.svg">
            <img class="changeimg" id="none" src="images/amplitud.svg">
            <img class="changeimg" id="none"  src="images/frecuencia.gif">
            <div class="changebutton">Cambiar</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: yes is possible... try it out and let us know how it goes

Answer (score 1):

Good evening! Yes, this is possible using jQuery; although if you are actually thinking about a carousel effect I suggest you, to use a plugin such as owlCarousel.

When you program using jQuery, you must think on how it is possible to manipulate the html through jQuery APIs. First, let us approach our problem through thinking.

First) We have four images that we wish to display one at a time within an interval time (the size in this case I recommend it to be always fixed eg. 400px by 400px or any other size, it does not matter).

Second) With jQuery we can grab each img element tag with a simple $('img'). We can do two things.

Solution I: We create an img element tag and style it depending on our wish with simple css for now (debugging purposes) and then, if this is our only img tag in our page, we actually can just grab that img () and save it to a var in JS as: var myImg = $('img'); Then using jQuery's awesome API, we can use a function called setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000); where inside the brackets is the code of the anonymous function we wish to execute, which is our first argument; the second argument is just the interval that the function will run over and over again until you stop it (in this case we do not).

But what kind of code will make it change? Well, this is called DOM manipulation. We actually can also change attribute values using another jQuery function provided in the API called .attr('attrName: desiredValue');

Here is the thinking logic behind the code, you must code it:

Save the img element tag in a variable using the jQuery selector. 
Inside an interval function, do a for loop from zero to n-number-of-pictures.
Inside the for loop, change the img src attribute value to whatever is the source of your image (you can have the sources of images defined inside of an array, it will be better, as imgSources = ['source1',...'sourceN'];) and loop equally with an i counter every n milliseconds. Or better yet, no for loop is needed, just assign the current counter i of the array value to the src attribute and increase it thereafter, and also add a sentinel, so that when it reaches a maximum, let us say array.length - 1 maximum, we reset to 0, good?

And try it. With this, we have an img tag that has a src attribute that will change every n milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible use absolute positioning and  the display attribute
here is a simple demo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .section {
            position: relative;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }
        
        .changeimg {
            position: absolute;
            display: none;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }
        
        .show {
            display: block;
        }
        
        .changebutton {
            width: 100px;
            position: relative;
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="section">
        <img class="changeimg show" id="first" style="background-color:aqua;" src="images/cresta.svg">
        <img class="changeimg" style="background-color:red  " src="images/longitud.svg">
        <img class="changeimg" style="background-color:black " src="images/amplitud.svg">
        <img class="changeimg" style="background-color:wheat " src="images/frecuencia.gif">
    </div>
    <div class="changebutton">Cambiar</div>
</body>
<script>
    $('.changebutton').click(function() {
        var show = $('.show');
        show.removeClass('show');
        if (show.next().length > 0) {
            show.next().addClass('show');
        } else {
            $('#first').addClass('show');
        }
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```js
jQuery("#clickme").click(
(function(){
    var i=0;
    function toogle(){
        jQuery(".changeimg").hide();
        jQuery(jQuery(".changeimg").get(i)).show();
        i+=1;
        if (i>jQuery(".changeimg").length)i=0;
    }
    return toogle;
})()
);
```

```css
img{
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="clickme">
            toogle the Rabbit yay!!
            </button> 
<div class="section">
            <img class="changeimg" src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/rabbit/rabbit-02.jpg">
            <img class="changeimg" src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/rabbit/rabbit-03.jpg">
            <img class="changeimg"  src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/rabbit/rabbit-07.jpg">
            <img class="changeimg"   src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/rabbit/rabbit-01.jpg">
            
        </div>
```